# How to apply [^0-9] regex pattern javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have id's validation method, each id can contain only `[a-z0-9_]` case insensitive characters. `[^a-z]` seems working, but I want to append `[^0-9]` but it's not work. How one string pattern should looks like?

```
function foo() {
  testUserIds = ['id23425860', 
  'yulka_rdtska',
  'im?sel=2000000001',
  'im?sel=2000000002'];
  for (id in testUserIds) {
    document.write(isUserIdValid(id) + '\r\n');
  }
}
function isUserIdValid(user_id) {
  var patt = new RegExp('[^a-z]', 'ig');
  return patt.test(user_id);
}
```

Comment: `[^a-z0-9]`. Put it inside the same character class.

Comment: I've tried that, it gives me wrong results: `false false false false`

Comment: Oh, man, sorry there just my erro in `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `for-in` construct instead of a proper `for` loop.  Use `[^a-z0-9_]` as your regular expression and iterate correctly over your array.

In JavaScript, don't iterate over arrays with `for (elem in arr)`, as that syntax's purpose is to iterate over properties of an object.  Instead use `for (var idx=0; idx<something; idx++)`.

```
function foo() {
  testUserIds = ['id23425860', 
  'yulka_rdtska',
  'im?sel=2000000001',
  'im?sel=2000000002'];

  // Use an incremental for loop here, NOT a for-in
  // for-in is intended for iterating over object properties, not arrays.
  for (var i=0; i<testUserIds.length; i++) {
    console.log(isUserIdValid(testUserIds[i]) + '\r\n');
  }
}
function isUserIdValid(user_id) {
  var patt = new RegExp('[^a-z0-9_]', 'ig');

  // Return the inversion of this, so isUserValid() is true if the user is valid
  return !patt.test(user_id);
}

foo();
// Outputs
true
true
false
false
```

Note that the way you have setup your function, it returns the *opposite* of what it says.  You are checking for invalid characters, so return the inverted:

```
// If it matched, it's invalid, otherwise valid
return !patt.test(user_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, just checked Google Javascript Style guide they say the same.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need:

```
function isUserIdValid(user_id) {
  var patt = new RegExp('[^a-z0-9_]', 'ig');
  return patt.test(user_id);
}
```

Comment: I found, my mistake was in `for` cycle I just passed index instead of values :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sometimes it takes talking out your problem to someone to help you find your mistakes. :P Dont forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var patt = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+$/, "ig");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isUserIdValid(user_id) {
    var patt = new RegExp(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i);
    return patt.test(user_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `testUserIds` with `var` so that it's a local variable, not a global one.

```
function foo() {
  var testUserIds = ['id23425860', 
  'yulka_rdtska',
  'im?sel=2000000001',
  'im?sel=2000000002'];

  // rest of your code
}
```

Also to declare a regular expression you can wrap the expression with slashes which is cleaner, like so:

```
var patt = /[^a-z]/ig;
```

A bit off-topic, but I couldn't help pointing out.